# Using react hooks inside NextJS /pages/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I would like to be able to use `react-hooks` inside an `API` call while using nextjs.

## Code

```
import { useQuery } from '../../../lib/apollo'
import { allAwards } from '../../../queries/awards'

export default (req, res) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(allAwards)
  res.status(200).json({ post: true, data })
}
```

## Error

```
Exiting builder due to build error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See `https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html` for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: _"Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function **component**"_ and you're not calling it inside the body of a function component.

Comment: Thanks Emile. But `()=>{}`  feels like a function to me no?

Comment: It's a function alright, just not a React component.

Comment: Oh interesting, files executed inside `pages/api` run as a standalone file. I did not realise this. So really this is just a lambda function?